# Signing a transaction server-side

Tags: web3js, transactions

I want to sign every transaction server side from the same address/wallet through web3.

What's the best way to tackle this?
Do I need to:

1. first use `web3.eth.sendTransaction`
2. Use `web3.eth.sign` to sign the transaction?

Cheers and happe new year!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just send the transaction immediately, `web3.eth.sendTransaction` is all you need (or just call a method on a contract or whatever you're doing).

If you want to sign the transaction in advance but not yet submit it to the network, you can use `web3.eth.signTransaction`.