# How to access ethereum smart contract functions from server side api calls using ExpressJS?

Tags: solidity, nodejs, external-api

I have the abi and bytecode of contract functions.

Is there a way to access them using api calls only(using web3 module or any other) since i want to integrate them in an android native app and thus can't use web3 plugin for front end javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [How to send transaction/call function from server-side?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57397/how-to-send-transaction-call-function-from-server-side/57444#57444).  I have put my node.js code in there for connecting from server. It is working fine for me.It may help you as well.

Comment: I am able to execute view functions using the snippet.
But  can't access any create function

Comment: Can you please share your code and the error you are getting.

Comment: nevermind it worked fine .. thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use web3j for Android because it’s java library

Comment: no i want to do it using apis only since i would be using them for web portal too.