# code: 'UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT, Error: cannot estimate gas

Tags: solidity, etherjs

Error:

[image]

Code:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");

const fs = require("fs-extra");
require("dotenv").config();

async function main() {
console.log(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC_URL);

//const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
const encryptedJson = fs.readFileSync(
"/media/kalki/030ABB616FC574C0/visualstudio/learnBlockchain/encrypted.json",
"utf8",
);

let wallet = new ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedJsonSync(
encryptedJson,
process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD,
);
wallet = await wallet.connect(provider);

const abiPath =
"/media/kalki/030ABB616FC574C0/visualstudio/learnBlockchain/simpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi";
const binaryPath =
"/media/kalki/030ABB616FC574C0/visualstudio/learnBlockchain/simpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin";
const abi = fs.readFileSync(abiPath, "utf8");
const binary = fs.readFileSync(binaryPath, "utf8");
const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
console.log("Deploying, please wait...");
const contract = await contractFactory.deploy();

const deploymentReceipt = await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1);
console.log(Contract deployed to ${contract.address});

let currentFavoriteNumber = await contract.retrieve();
console.log(Current Favorite NumbAer: ${currentFavoriteNumber});
console.log("Updating favorite number...");
let transactionResponse = await contract.store(7);
let transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1);
currentFavoriteNumber = await contract.retrieve();
console.log(New Favorite Number: ${currentFavoriteNumber});
}

main()
.then(() => process.exit(0))
.catch((error) => {
console.error(error);
process.exit(1);
});
```

I am using alchemy for rpc url and my fake metamask account has
0.9593Sepolia ETH and 40 links

[image]

Comment: **You can refer this link** :https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57397/how-to-send-transaction-call-function-from-server-side/155357#155357